# Spring Boot 4.9.0 ThymeLeaf auto-complete not working in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf

I would like to use SpringBoot with Thymeleaf. I created a controller, which looks like this:

I have the Controller Structure like this:

```
@Controller
public class AboutController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/about" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String about()
    {
        System.out.println("inside about");
        return "about";
    }
}
```

And having the dependency in pom.xml :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

In about.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hi Thyme leaf Example</h1>
    <h1 th:  ></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The suggestion/auto-complete is not showing of th:  ...

I am using

- JDK 1.8
- Spring boot 2.4.2
- Thymeleaf 3.0

Comment: Spring Boot 4.9.0 does not exist. The currently existing versions are 2.3.8 and 2.4.2

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Yes, You are right , I am using spring tools which is 4.9.0 version ,and spring boot version 2.4.2 https://spring.io/tools

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has to do with Spring Boot at all, I think you need the Thymeleaf Eclipse plug-in from https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-eclipse-plugin to have that completion.

Comment: But still the suggestion is not showing in .html files, even with out spring boot     @nitind

Answer (score 0):

Right click project icon ----> click Maven ----> Update project ----> check all as shown in blow pic ( [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Dnh.png )-----> Ok ------> wait for the project to update. -----> Restart STS

if still it does not work
goto help ----> install new software ----> manage ----- Select Thymeleaf -----> reload-----> apply and close  -----> Restart STS